# Optimizing View with 54 SELECTs -- Updated with Process used

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, view, query-optimization

I've started a new job and am looking at some of their views that they wanted me to get familiar with.

One of the views that I'm going through has **54 SELECTs**.  I've NEVER seen such a massive View before and after browsing through it, I'm fairly certain that I can optimize it.

What I'm looking for is an easier way to compare the JOINs between each of the selects to find commonality WITHOUT just having to sift through them all by hand.

I'm fairly certain that THAT is what I'll have to do, but I was hoping that someone would have an easier or more efficient and less time consuming way to do this...

Anyone? :)

Comment: You can always run EXPLAIN on the query that defines the view. But no, I'm afraid optimizing it is going to be a lengthy and painstaking process.

Comment: What's the basic structure of the view? Are all the selects in unions, sub selects in the from clause? How are they joined, exactly? It is hard to help with out more detail about the structure.

Comment: @BillKarwin I hadn't thought of that.  That might help, though it's an Oracle database and I'm not familiar with what the equivalent would be if there's not an EXPLAIN.

Comment: @Acroyear Overarching structure is 54 SELECTs UNION'd together.  Some of them have subqueries in them that are similar across some of the SELECTs.

Comment: What is the number of unique TABLEs that are referenced?

Comment: Are they similar queries overall (i.e. are they something that could be collapsed into one or more queries with conditional aggregation)? I think you're stuck with manually overhauling the view, but you could maybe split each query out into a file and then use a file comparison tool (e.g. winmerge) to compare them?

Comment: Oracle has [EXPLAIN PLAN](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9010.htm#SQLRF01601), which is similar in purpose to EXPLAIN in other brands of RDBMS, but the output is bound to be different, so you should read documentation to understand how to interpret it.

Comment: If I had just begun at a new gig I would look to start with something simpler than a 54 query view. Very possibly you can improve it but I suspect you'll need to invest a lot of time and energy in understanding it before you'll produce any visible output. For starters, do they have regression tests in place? The other thing is, have you spoken to your new colleagues about this view? There may be some very good reasons why it's such a behemoth.

Comment: @APC To be honest, I'm just trying to understand it first.  But my mind keeps jumping to the sheer size of the thing... I have broken out each SELECT into it's own file and I'm using WinMerge, but there's 54 SELECTs...

-_-

Comment: Please post one or two of those selects for our comments

Comment: @donPablo  What do you mean by post the selects "for our comments"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update 12/4/2019:
TLDR; I separated each main SELECT into it's own file, then using Notepad++ on the full view code file I found common values to sort and organize each individual SELECT into a folder named the common value.  From there I used WinMerge to compare each group of SELECTs in their respective folders against each other to find differences and commonalities.  I then started refactoring and minimizing the excessive code (and table calls >.< ) using CTE's (because this is Oracle and a View).

---

I ended up splitting out the views SELECTs by looking for one of the field names that's a column in the view. This meant that I'd get the beginnings of each SELECT.

I then copied and pasted each one into a different .sql file. I also saved the full view into it's own .sql file.

Using Notepad++ I searched for each instance of the view column name and took down the column value that is the main information needed for the view. Using that information, I grouped each SELECT into a folder based on that value

Once I'd gotten all the SELECTs into their respective folders, I used WinMerge to the SELECTs to the others in their same folder.  This helped me to locate commonalities and differences, some differences that would be harder to lump the datasource table into a CTE with the others.

I've since been updating, refactoring, and fixing the view one folder grouped SELECTs at a time.

The project I'm in has had me touching each one of the main code values that I had used to organize the SELECTs into folders, so I WILL end up recoding the ENTIRE view. :)

Comment: If you are using Oracle 12.2 or greater take a look at PL/Scope. You can find the SQL ids in your code and group by duplicates:

https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_EIFVZ425KN2YJGOP7IFD04LZO.html

(samples by Steven Feuerstein not me)

Comment: @JoãoBarreto Oh!  I think that I am. I'll check it out, and probably wish that I had know about it before I started this process. >.<  Something I can use for the future, I'm sure though. :)

Comment: @JoãoBarreto Okay so I did take a look at the PL/Scope, but it wouldn't have helped me since all the statements were in the same View.  It seems that PL/Scope is used to find similar code between two "different" objects in the database.  But I'll keep this in mind if I need something like this later.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention it in my comment. I read that you had everything in one view, I actually been through that and was able to temporarily transform the view into several SELECT INTO in a pl/sql block only to use PL/Scope to find the duplicates. Nevertheless it is always great to add another tool to your belt.

Answer (score 1):

Identifying similar lines of code is a difficult problem, and as far as I know [Clone Doctor](http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/Clone/) is the only program that can do it for PL/SQL.

I only used it once, about 10 years ago.  But I remember being surprised at how well it found different lines of code that were really duplicates at a deep level.  It wasn't perfect, and had some bugs and took a while to get working.  But there's a free trial version.

Comment: But views aren't PL/SQL

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It's been a long time since I've used it, I can't remember if it can analyze views, or if the view will need to be embedded into a temporary PL/SQL object.  These kind of advanced language tools often require a lot of setup to get working, which is why it's usually best to do things manually unless there's a *lot* of code.

Comment: Thank you for the link, but I'm not allowed to download unapproved applications and the process to get that done was going to take longer than I'd have to get the first edit done.  THANK YOU THOUGH!  It looks like that application would have helped.